# WCF Same IParameterInspector for all operations on a service

Tags: wcf, extensibility

I have implemented a custom `IParameterInspector` and I want to have it execute for every single operation on my service.

My understanding is that `IParameterInspector` implementations can only be used with `IOperationBehavior` implementations, and that intern `IOperationBehavior` implementation can only be used to decorate individual operations using an attribute.

Does anyone know if there is a way I can register my `IParameterInspector` at a service level so that it can execute for all operations in the service?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Thanks to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2207001/generic-logging-of-operation-parameters-in-wcf) and subsequenbtly [this](http://weblogs.asp.net/paolopia/archive/2007/08/23/writing-a-wcf-message-inspector.aspx), I found what I was looking for.

`IParameterInspector` does not need to be at the `IOperationBehavior` level. They can be at the `IServiceBehavior` level. In the service level  `ApplyDispatchBehavior` method you need to loop through all its operations and assign the inspector behaviour.

My class in full...

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class)]
public class ServiceLevelParameterInspectorAttribute : Attribute, IParameterInspector, IServiceBehavior
{
    public object BeforeCall(string operationName, object[] inputs)
    {
       // Inspect the parameters.
        return null;
    }

    public void AfterCall(string operationName, object[] outputs, object returnValue, object correlationState)
    {
    }

    public void Validate(ServiceDescription serviceDescription, ServiceHostBase serviceHostBase)
    {
    }

    public void AddBindingParameters(ServiceDescription serviceDescription, ServiceHostBase serviceHostBase, Collection<ServiceEndpoint> endpoints, BindingParameterCollection bindingParameters)
    {
    }

    public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(ServiceDescription serviceDescription, ServiceHostBase serviceHostBase)
    {
        foreach (ChannelDispatcher channelDispatcher in serviceHostBase.ChannelDispatchers)
        {
            if (channelDispatcher == null)
            {
                continue;
            }

            foreach(var endPoint in channelDispatcher.Endpoints)
            {
                if (endPoint == null)
                {
                    continue;
                }

                foreach(var opertaion in endPoint.DispatchRuntime.Operations)
                {
                    opertaion.ParameterInspectors.Add(this);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @itchi Even older now, but i'm guessing because "The collection contains ChannelDispatcherBase objects (and not just instances of ChannelDispatcher) because it is also used by developers who want to keep the Windows Communication Foundation (WCF) programming model but replace the system-provided runtime". Looks like the code could trigger an invalid cast exception. Would be better to use keep ChannelDispatcherBase and use the "as" operator.